# Python regex, negate a set of characters in between a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have several set of strings with numbers followed words and jumbled numbers and words etc.
For example,

```
"Street 50 No 40", "5, saint bakers holy street", "32 Syndicate street"
```

I am trying to separate the street names from the apartment numbers.

Here is my current code:

```
import re 

pattern_street = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+\s?\w+\s?[A-Za-z]+\s?[A-Za-z]+',re.X)
pattern_apartmentnumber = re.compile(r'(^\d+\s? | [A-Za-z]+[\s?]+[0-9]+$)',re.X)

for i in ["Street 50 No 40", "5, saint bakers holy street", "32 Syndicate street"]:
    
    match_street = pattern_street.search(i) 
    match_apartmentnumber = pattern_apartmentnumber.search(i)

    fin_street = match_street[0]
    fin_apartmentnumber = match_apartmentnumber[0]

    print("street--",fin_street)
    print("apartmentnumber--",fin_apartmentnumber)
```

which prints:

```
street-- Street 50 No
apartmentnumber-- No 40
street-- saint bakers holy street
apartmentnumber-- 5
street-- Syndicate street
apartmentnumber-- 32
```

I want to remove the "No" from the first street name. **i.e. if there is any street with `No` followed by a number at the end, that needs to be taken as the apartment number,
and not as the street.**
How can I do this for my above example strings?

Comment: I like this construct `[\s?]+`, spaces inside a regex ARE important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try the case where there is a `No 123` at the end, use a positive lookahead.

If not found try a street without this.

```
pattern_street = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+[\s\w]+(?=\s[Nn]o\s\d+$)|[A-Za-z]+[\s\w]+',re.X)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the street name by the following regex pattern to eliminate ***No [0-9]*** from the statement.

```
pattern_street = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+((?!No).)+',re.X)
```